# PHP CURL Authentication error code 302

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I need to send a post request with authentication.

I try this code but I get error 302.

```
$url = "https://wifinext.internavigare.com/prepagataAnagrafica/creaUtente/";
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypassword';
// create a new cURL resource
$ch= curl_init($url);

// do a POST request, using application/x-www-form-urlencoded type
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// credentials
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
// returns the response instead of displaying it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//Set Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Prepagata_codice=Test&Prepagata_password=123456");

// do request, the response text is available in $response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// status code, for example, 200
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//show response
echo $statusCode;
echo $response;

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

I see some answer say to use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION or cookies and I try it but I cannot figure out how to do. I'm about to pull out my hair. Please some help is really appreciated.

Comment: Same here! Anybody knows how to fix this? I would like to make just a request to another php file through url. However I'm getting the same 302 http code

Answer (score 0):

status code `302` means the url redirects to another url. Set the curl option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true to follow this redirect.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: Thenks for your answer I try it but then the login page is displayed. I have no idea what I have to do after.

Comment: That depends on what you are making. I don't know what the functionality of your application is. If you have other questions, please mark this question as solved and create a new question.

Comment: As you can see by the code I posted I need to send this post fields to the page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Prepagata_codice=Test&Prepagata_password=123456");
However if I use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION seam that it only bring to the login page instead of authenticate

Comment: I thank you for your time and really appreciate your effort but I cannot mark the answer as solved because as I wrote in my post I was alredy able to add the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION but my problem is that just this seam to not authenticate and I dont know what I have to do after the redirect

Answer (score 0):

Please try to pass the POST data as array.

```
$postData = array('Prepagata_codice' => 'Test', 'Prepagata_password' => '1234');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```